# How to get height of a div in sencha touch 2?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I need to get the height of a div

I did it with plain js like:

```
var inner = document.getElementById("inner").offsetHeight;
```

but, doesn't work when i am in another tab, so I try to use `Ext`.

I try this, but doesn't work:

```
var innerdiv = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode("inner");

var inner = innerdiv.getHeight();
```

I couldn't find any example.

which is the best way to get the height of a div?

Comment: did you used css or style attribute to set height ?

Comment: no, height is determined by the text in the div

Answer (score 2):

When using `Ext.DomQuery.selectNode`, you have to have your selector right.  If `inner` is an ID, you need a `#` in front of it:

```
var innerHeight = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode("#inner").getHeight();
```

Comment: LOL, how I could do such an error? I should sleep more, ahahah. This is what I found this morning: http://imgur.com/lNzVkjo

Comment: DIV is selected, but I get Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getHeight'

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
Ext.DomQuery.selectNode("#test").offsetHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working example [here.](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/element.html)

```
var dimSz = Ext.get('dim-sizing');
var padding = dimSz.getPadding('lrtb'); // has value of 0px
var border = dimSz.getBorderWidth('lrtb'); // has value of 0px
var height = dimSz.getHeight(); // has value of 1691px
var width = dimSz.getWidth(); // has value of 895px
```

First get the DIV id with Ext.get, then get its dimensions with the functions.

Still doesn't work if the DIV is in a different (not visible) tab, (probably because the height of the DIV is 0)